# TypeScript variables are undefined even after i initialized them in constructor. Full typescript code is provided below

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

**I have some variables like seconds, miliseconds, minutes, interval etc.**
I am initializing all variables in constructor and using them in startinterval, stopinterval functions.

On window load I have called init function and attached events to button based on their id, but when I click start button undefined error is raised on this.timerId.

Html and type script code is provided below.

Need to know what I am doing wrong.

HTML Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Timer</h1>
    <a id="minutes">1</a><a id="seconds">1</a><a id="miliseconds">1</a>
    <button id="btnStart" value="Start" >Start</button>
    <button id="btnPause" value="Pause" >Pause</button>
    <button id="btnStop" value="Stop" >Clear</button>
</body>

</html>
```

JS Code

```js
class Timer {
    seconds: number;
    miliseconds: number;
    minutes: number;
    interval: number;
    timerId: number;

    constructor() {
        this.seconds = 0;
        this.miliseconds = 0;
        this.minutes = 0;
        this.interval = 25;
        this.timerId = -1;
    }

    startTimer = function () {
        if (this.timerId == -1) {
            window.setInterval('this.timerActivate()', this.interval);
        }
    };

    pauseTimer = function () {
        window.clearInterval(this.timerId);
        this.timerId = -1;
    };

    stopTimer = function () {
        this.pauseTimer();
        this.miliseconds = 0;
        this.seconds = 0;
        this.minutes = 0;
        this.displayTimer();
    };

    displayTimer = function () {
        document.getElementById('miliseconds').innerHTML = this.miliseconds.toString();
        document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = this.seconds.toString();
        document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = this.minutes.toString();
    };

    timerActivate = function () {
       
        this.miliseconds += this.interval;

        if (this.miliseconds >= 1000) {
            this.miliseconds = 0;
            this.seconds += 1;
        }

        if (this.seconds >= 60) {
            this.miliseconds = 0;
            this.seconds = 0;
            this.minutes += 1;
        }

        this.displayTimer();
    };

    init = function (startButton: string, pauseButton: string, clearButton: string) {
        document.getElementById(startButton).addEventListener('click', this.startTimer, false);
        document.getElementById(pauseButton).addEventListener('click', this.pauseTimer, false);
        document.getElementById(clearButton).addEventListener('click', this.stopTimer, false);

        this.displayTimer();
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    var timer = new Timer();
    timer.init("btnStart", "btnPause", "btnStop");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `'click', this.startTimer, false` with `'click', () => this.startTimer(), false`?

Comment: Yup this worked, Can you please explain me more about this how it works () =>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your context (`this`) changes when you use the `function () {}` syntax or pass an unbound function reference. You can do a couple of things.

Change your function definitions to use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
startTimer = () => {
    if (this.timerId == -1) {
        window.setInterval('this.timerActivate()', this.interval);
    }
};
```

Or wrap your event listeners inside an arrow function:

```
document.getElementById(startButton).addEventListener('click', () => this.startTimer(), false);
```

Comment: Yes this worked, Thanks a lot. Can you please explain me more I need to understand this () => concept better.

Comment: @yashshukla See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this). Basically `this` inside arrow functions are the same as the `this` in its surrounding context. But with `fuunction() {}` it varies based on how the function is called.